# List of diagram / image editors for Delphi

Tags: delphi, image, diagram

I need a good diagram / image editor for a Delphi application. I need the ability to place an image in the editor, and use freely positioned balloons / tips to describe parts of the image. The result must be exported as an image.

So far, I have evaluated [KSDev Block Engine](http://www.ksdev.com/blockengine/index.html) and [TMS Diagram studio](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/diagram.asp) but am not completely satisfied with both of them. The former seems to have lots of little quirks and bugs and both of them don't seem to be able to export their content as an image (PNG with alpha channels is required).

Are there any other editors you know of that I might evaluate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two free components that I know of and have evaluated for a very limited period.
1) drawobjects by Angus Johnson @ http://angusj.com/delphi/
2) simple graph from the delphiarrea site.

If I remember correctly both have the ability to export to an image format but I do not recall if they support png with alpha.

Regards
jo

PS sorry the anti spam does not allow me to post the link for the second pack and since I hate any kind of sign in just to answer a question my email and name are fake. This is the last time I am going to visit this site. I do understand the need to keep the spammers out but I can't accept any one to assume that I am a spammer. BB everyone.

Comment: What's the problem with signing in? You can even use an existing openID account. Without signing in all the nice reputation features of SO wouldn't work. And there's just no way to decide whether you are a spammer or not...

Comment: I tend to agree with Smasher, especially as your answer has been really helpful: both of the components seem to be excellent. Thank you.

Comment: That site no longer appears to require a login. The simple graph component is here: http://www.delphiarea.com/products/delphi-components/simplegraph/

Answer (score 0):

Have also a look at: 
- TeeTree from steema.com
- TCad from codeidea.com